# MapStruct: Map two sources and return null if one of them is null

Tags: mapstruct

I could not find an answer and I believe this is not possible with MapStruc. I would like to ask anyway, maybe I missed something.

I have a mapping method that takes two sources and maps to one target, let's say

```
@Mapping(...)
@Mapping(...)
...
Target mapToTarget(SourceA a, SourceB b);
```

The generated code does the following `null` check to return `null`:

```
if (a == null && b == null) return null;
```

I wish to have

```
if (a == null || b == null) return null;
```

For the moment I filter beforehand so that I won't give `null` as input. I wish to skip that part and simply return `null` in the mapper if an argument is `null`.

Does MapStruct support this?

P.S.: We use MapStruct 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with MapStruct. However, you can achieve this by providing a default method.

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class CustomerMapper {

    public Target mapToTarget(SourceA a, SourceB b) {
        if (a == null || b == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return mapToTargetWithMapStruct(a, b);
    }

    @Named("ignore") // @Named in order for MapStruct not to consider this as a candidate
    protected abstract mapToTargetWithMapStruct(SourceA a, SourceB b);

}
```